# query locator with string query or sobject list

Tags: apex, batch, querylocator

Using the `Database.QueryLocator` object bypasses the governor limit for the total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries. One could implement one of the following methods to get the QueryLocator:

```
global static Database.QueryLocator getQueryLocator(List<SObject> query){}

global static Database.QueryLocator getQueryLocator(String query){}
```

I see many [examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) in the salesforce site using `Database.QueryLocator getQueryLocator(String query)` instead of `Database.QueryLocator getQueryLocator(List<SObject> query)`.

Why using `Database.QueryLocator getQueryLocator(String query)`? It is easier to make mistakes using a query string. Does `Database.QueryLocator getQueryLocator(List<SObject> query)` also retrieve at most 50 million records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Database.QueryLocator getQueryLocator(List<SObject> query)` only works with an inline query.

The following would compile:

```
public class SuperBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext param1) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext param1, List<Account> accountsList) {
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext param1) {
    }
}
```

The following would NOT compile:

```
public class SuperBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext param1) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(getAccounts());
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext param1, List<Account> accountsList) {
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext param1) {
    }

    private List<Account> getAccounts(){
        return [SELECT Id FROM Account];
    }
}
```

The last example would not compile and salesforce would show the error message:

> Argument must be an inline query

***Why using `Database.QueryLocator getQueryLocator(String query)`?***

- Using `Database.QueryLocator getQueryLocator(String query)` allows [code reusability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse), since once could write a query string in a method and use it elsewhere.

**Does `Database.QueryLocator getQueryLocator(List<SObject> query)` also
retrieve at most 50 million records?**

- Yes, it does.